# Problem with API-Gateway GET method and Lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I am using swift UI for a stories app in which a user once logged in via the Cognito can read a story on the app screen. The user can also like the story for which I am using Dynamodb table, API Gateway and Lambda function. The backend is working well in which the likes are inserted and incremented correctly, but locally the likes are not loaded. I am using the same API gateway with post and get methods, and the same lambda function both for loading likes and incrementing likes. I am also using Custom Domain Name -> Route 53 -> Cloudfront with OAI -> S3 where the stories text are stored.  Cloudfront also allows for full GET, POST and other methods, although this might be relevant here, but still if that can be considered an issue.

Will really appreciate if anyone can help me figure this out?!!

[DynamoDBTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82Sc9.png)

[LambdaIntegration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5SXE.png)

[APIGateway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DS7Su.png)

[AppScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEEh3.jpg)

Like Button action code below with on.Appear. Last code the manageLike function

```
// Like button as an overlay
                    Button(action: {
                        self.isLiked.toggle()
                        //self.insertLike(increment: self.isLiked) // Pass the isLiked state as the increment flag
                        self.manageLike(action: "insert", increment: self.isLiked)
                    }) {
                        Image(isLiked ? "like-image-filled" : "like-image")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                    }
                    
                }
                .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                .background(Color.white.opacity(0.5))
                .cornerRadius(12)
                .padding([.top, .trailing])
            }
            .onAppear {
                //self.loadLikeCount()  // Load the like count when the view appears
                self.manageLike(action: "load")
                print("StoryContentView_07 rendering content: \(storyContent)")
            }
```

```
// Combined function for loading like count and inserting like
    private func manageLike(action: String, increment: Bool = false) {
        let url = URL(string: apiGatewayURL)
        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        
        if action == "load" {
            request.httpMethod = "GET"
            request.url = URL(string: "\(apiGatewayURL)?storyId=\(storyId)")
        } else if action == "insert" {
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            let body: [String: Any] = ["storyId": storyId, "increment": increment]
            request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body)
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print("Network request failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "unknown error")")
                return
            }
            
            if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    do {
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any]
                        if let likeCount = json?["likeCount"] as? Int {
                            self.likeCount = likeCount
                            self.likeCount += 1  // Increment the local like count state
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print("JSON parsing error: \(error)")
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print("HTTP Error: Status code \(String(describing: (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode))")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

Also, here is my lambda function code:

```
import json
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('StoryLikes')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        if event['httpMethod'] == 'POST':
            body = json.loads(event.get('body', '{}'))
            story_id = body['storyId']
            increment = body.get('increment', False)

            response = table.get_item(Key={'storyId': story_id})

            if 'Item' not in response:
                table.put_item(Item={'storyId': story_id, 'likeCount': 1})
                return {'statusCode': 201, 'body': json.dumps({'likeCount': 1})}
            else:
                if increment:
                    new_like_count = response['Item']['likeCount'] + 1
                    table.update_item(
                        Key={'storyId': story_id},
                        UpdateExpression='SET likeCount = :val',
                        ExpressionAttributeValues={':val': new_like_count}
                    )
                    return {'statusCode': 200, 'body': json.dumps({'likeCount': new_like_count})}
                else:
                    return {'statusCode': 200, 'body': json.dumps({'likeCount': response['Item']['likeCount']})}

        elif event['httpMethod'] == 'GET':
            story_id = event['queryStringParameters']['storyId']
            response = table.get_item(Key={'storyId': story_id})
            
            if 'Item' in response:
                return {'statusCode': 200, 'body': json.dumps({'likeCount': response['Item']['likeCount']})}
            else:
                return {'statusCode': 200, 'body': json.dumps({'likeCount': 0})}

    except ClientError as e:
        return {'statusCode': 500, 'body': json.dumps({'error': str(e)})}
    except KeyError as e:
        return {'statusCode': 400, 'body': json.dumps({'error': f'Missing key: {str(e)}'})}
```

When the screen of the story is first loaded I get a 403 error, that's when the loading of the likes action is expected to happen - the GET request. And then when I tap on the likes, I get 502 error that's when the POST request should happen. But it's confusing that my POST method correctly insert and increment likes in the backend where the dynamodb table is correctly updated, but it's just these are not shown on the front end UI, perhaps it's not updated correctly.

Have checked for the following, the IAM policies are correctly configured with fullDynamoDBAccess, but still there the likes are not loaded locally. Now I am not sure if it's a frontend UI update issue or backend issue.

1. **HTTP 403 Forbidden**: This status code indicates that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it. This could happen due to several reasons:

   - **IAM Permissions**: The AWS IAM role associated with the Lambda function or API Gateway may not have the correct permissions to access the DynamoDB table or other required resources.
   - **API Gateway Configuration**: The API Gateway may be configured to require certain headers, query parameters, or use an authorizer that your request isn't meeting.
   - **Cognito Authentication**: If you're using Amazon Cognito for user authentication, ensure that the credentials are being passed correctly and that they have the necessary permissions.
2. **HTTP 502 Bad Gateway**: This indicates that the server received an invalid response from the upstream server (in this case, probably your Lambda function).

   - **Lambda Function Error**: There might be an issue with the Lambda function itself. Check the CloudWatch logs for the Lambda function to see if there's an error being logged when the function is invoked.
   - **API Gateway Integration**: The 502 error can also occur if the API Gateway is not correctly integrated with the Lambda function, such as if the response format from Lambda does not match what API Gateway expects.

[CognitoIdentityPool Role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nhx54.png)

[LambdaFunctionIAM Role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ITSF.png)